# Define Android drawable XML attribute as child

Tags: android, android-layout

Say I have a button defined in XML roughly as follows, embedded in `layout/activity.xml`:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/a_button"
    android:background="@drawable/a_unique_drawable"/>
```

Separately I have defined `drawable/a_unique_drawable.xml`. Is it possible to define the drawable in line with the button? Given that the drawable is unique to the particular button and used in no other places I believe it could improve clarity to have everything defined together. I'm looking for something roughly like:

```
<Button ...>
    <android:background>{contents of drawable XML}</android:background>
</Button>
```

I could also be convinced this is a terrible idea but I'm nevertheless curious if it's possible.

Comment: There is no way to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not possible. In addition to that, you can define more options as resources, styles, themes - so why to make an inline coding?